Getting isort to distinguish first and third party packages when using a venv and VSCode
I'm trying to configure isort and would like to have my first and third party packages separate, eg, code from my local, and then code from packages I install. I'm using Pipenv to manage my packages, which creates a venv.
When isort triggers vs VScode, it groups all my local imports with the packages I've installed into my venv. When I run isort in the venv, it creates two groups.
VSCode does recognize the venv (on the bottom status bar, it shows the path to the venv).
EDIT: More testing show it has to do with the location of my isort.cfg. My root directory has an api folder, a frontend folder, a docker folder, and a few global files. The isort.cfg is in the api folder. isort doesn't work properly when my vscode is using the root as my workspace, but if I create a new vscode instance with the api folder as the root, it works as expected. So the question becomes how to get it working from the main root, besides creating another config file.
